# lowercase the result of a select and look for it in another select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement

```
SELECT EmployeeID 
FROM ApplicationStatus 
LEFT JOIN Employee ON EmployeeID = email 
WHERE role <= 2 
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

It returns a bunch of emails entered by employees. It could be capital, lowercase or mixed case. I don't know and I'm not allowed to modify the data.

```
SELECT CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID 
FROM ApplicationStatus 
WHERE LOWER(EmployeeID) IN LOWER(result from above statement) 
ORDER BY EventDateTime;
```

I feel like I am close but I can't find out what I need to make them both lowercase (or upppercase). I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: Is your collation case sensitive? What is the schema of the table - an Id would naturally be an integer?

Comment: If, however, you're not using a case sensitive collation, then there is no need for the 2 `LOWER` functions on the functions. For something like an ID (based on the name `EmployeeID`), then *if* you are using a case sensitive collation changing the clause to use lower case letters is going to only cause data errors; likely meaning that the `LOWER` isn't required at all. If it *is* and there is inconsistency between the casing in the 2 tables you have a bigger problem: a lack of foreign keys and referential integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Stu and @Larnu: if you're dealing with a case-insensitive collation then you don't need to call `Lower()` in your comparisons i.e. `HELLO` would be considered equal to `hello`.

However, if your collation is case-sensitive then you're very nearly there!

`Lower()` can be applied to a single, scalar value.

Your `IN Lower(<SELECT statement>)` is attempting to apply it to a *set*, which won't work.

```sql
SELECT CustomerID
     , EventType
     , EventDateTime
     , Comments
     , EmployeeID 
FROM   ApplicationStatus
WHERE  Lower(EmployeeID) IN (SELECT Lower(EmployeeID) FROM your_other_query)
ORDER
   BY EventDateTime
;
```